# graphite/grafana alert on message queue

Tags: metrics, grafana, graphite

We have the wait time of a message in a queue being fed into Graphite, recorded with Coda Hale’s Metrics library. And then we have Grafana graphing that time. I'm trying to come up with a sensible alert based on the wait time, but I'm seeing constant alerts. It's possible that they are legitimate, but I'm having a hard time finding examples to compare with and I wonder if the alert is doing what I think it's doing. 
I would appreciate feedback and any advice from someone who is doing anything similar. What I’m looking to alert on right now is when a message has been waiting longer than the 98th percentile of the recorded message wait time. My queries are
A: aliasByNode(...waitTime.p98, 9)
B: timeShift(...waitTime.p98, '5min'),
C: asPercent(#B, #A)
My alert is 
when avg() of query(C, 5m, now) is above 100

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use [movingAverage](http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.movingAverage)`(...waitTime.p98, '1hour')` rather than `timeShift(...waitTime.p98, '5min')`.

That will give you a final query of `asPercent(...waitTime.p98,movingAverage(...waitTime.p98, '1hour'))` which will compute the value for each interval as a percentage of the average over the previous 1 hour rolling window.  When you then take a 5-minute average over that with the alert you'll get a value that is effectively the average of the last 5 minutes compared to the average of the last 1hr 5min.

Another way to do this is to use `asPercent(movingaverage(...waitTime.p98, '5min'), movingAverage(...waitTime.p98, '1hour'))` and just take the current value.  It's not 100% identical but will be easier to reason about because you can plot it and see exactly what the alert is firing on.